# How can I benchmark async vs sync python code?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, async-await, python-asyncio

I need to write a benchmark to compare speed of execution of a both synchronous and asynchronous python program but I'm not sure what is the correct way to compare them. My script query the Elasticsearch and return the response to the client.

```py
import asyncio
import json
import multiprocessing
import timeit
import time
import socket
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, AsyncElasticsearch


es = Elasticsearch()
es_lock = threading.Lock()

aes = AsyncElasticsearch()
aes_lock = threading.Lock()


def _generate_query():
    return {'query': {'match_all': {}}}


def _sync_es_server(query, index='test-index'):
    global es
    with es_lock:
        return es.search(
            index=index, body=query
        )


async def _async_es_server(query, index='test-index'):
    global aes
    with aes_lock:
        return await aes.search(
            index=index, body=query
        )


def server(benchmark_sync=True):

    def sync_server():
        def handler(conn):
            response = _sync_es_server(query=_generate_query())
            conn.send(json.dumps(response).encode())
            conn.close()
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 55441))
        s.listen()
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as worker:
            while True:
                conn, addr = s.accept()
                worker.submit(handler, conn)

    async def async_server():
        async def handler(reader, writer):
            response = await _async_es_server(query=_generate_query(), index='ghasedak_stage_web_post')
            writer.write(json.dumps(response).encode())
            await writer.drain()
        http_server = await asyncio.start_server(
            handler, '127.0.0.1', 55441
        )
        await http_server.serve_forever()

    if benchmark_sync:
        sync_server()
    else:
        asyncio.run(async_server())


def hammer_server(n_requests=10):
    def request_server():
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 55441))
            s.sendall(b'')
            data = s.recv(2**16 - 1)
    threads = [
        threading.Thread(target=request_server, args=()) for _ in range(n_requests)
    ]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


process = multiprocessing.Process(target=server, args=(False,))
process.start()


time.sleep(1)

print(
    timeit.timeit("hammer_server()", globals=globals(), number=1)
)
```

When I run the `server` with `benchmark_sync=False` it never response more than one request. I have two questions here:

- Am I using async feature in a wrong way that it can not response more than one request?
- Is my approach to compare sync and async code correct?